# How to harvest XNA content files using WiX?

Tags: xna, wix, build-automation

Ideally I'd be grabbing the outputs from the project spec itself, but heat.exe doesn't seem to support `contentproj` files as a project type, nor does it pick up the content if I pass in the game's main `csproj`.

Currently I have a pre-build step calling heat on the output folder, but that (a) feels dirty, and (b) produces a bunch of `File` tags referencing the source paths relative to the output folder, such that the build fails when it can't find them relative to the WiX project's folder.

I should note that I'm using Votive and my project layout looks like this:

```
- Main solution
 - XNA "Metaproject" Folder
  - Game
   - bin/x86/Release (GameContent output appears here)
  - GameContent
 - WiX Project
```

I would very much like to minimize the number of times I have to specify a path like `"../../Game/Game/bin/x86/Release/Content"`, because that's error-prone and depressing to type out. Prods in the right direction appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a contentproj is just a collection of files, what you can do is add the harvesting directly within the wixproj that is creating the installer:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <HarvestDirectoryNoLogo>true</HarvestDirectoryNoLogo>
    <HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments>true</HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments>
    <HarvestDirectorySuppressUniqueIds>true</HarvestDirectorySuppressUniqueIds>
    <HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids>true</HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' " 
                      Include="$(SolutionDir)\GameContent">
        <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLDIR</DirectoryRefId>
        <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
        <PreprocessorVariable>var.GameContentDir</PreprocessorVariable>
        <ComponentGroupName>GameContent</ComponentGroupName>
    </HarvestDirectory>    
</ItemGroup>
```

You will need to add this manually to the wixproj file and you can repeat the HarvestDirectory for each directory if you require more than one.

To set the `var.GameContentDir` pre-processor variable edit the DefineConstants property:

```
<DefineConstants>GameContentDir=$(GameContentDir);</DefineConstants>
```

which will set the pre-processor var to the msbuild property:

```
<GameContentDir>$(SolutionDir)\GameContent</GameContentDir>
```

which means you can then modify this dependant on the build configuration. If you don't need to modify the path, just set a static value in the `<DefineConstants>` property.

This will then generate a wxs file in the obj directory each build which is then included assuming you have included the ComponentGroupName. If you have included the one you previously generated in your wixproj remove it as you will get conflicts if the ComponentGroupName is the same.